# Wordpress Divi Blurbs with Toggle buttons

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a page that has a grid of 4 columns each column contains a blurb and a below the blurb it contains a toggle. The blurb text content is not the same. My issues is once I have aligned the toggle buttons of each the column. The toggle buttons do not align. How can I set the blurb and Toggles to line up without plenty of spacing ? I have used `align-items:flex-end` any other methods I could try align.

Answer (score 0):

Share link will be more helpful to understand the problem. Question is still not clear to me. If its happening on Divi Latest version then check if there having div before the button tag by inspecting the button. If you are confused just take row or column and then put button inside that. It should work.

As usual button contain a or button tag which is not block level element but text level so its taking display as inline or flex instead of block and getting element only spacing. So you ned to put text level element inside block level wrap like first div then button tag to make it alignment. Hope it will help you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your question that the blurb in each column is a different length, so the toggles do not line up horizontally? To line them up in Divi, first you'll need to make sure the columns are equal heights, and add a class to the row:

1. In the row settings, go to the **Design** tab, and enable **Equalize Column Height**.
2. Also in the row settings, go to the **Advanced** tab, and add a **Custom CSS Class** `custom_fixed_toggles`.

Now add the CSS to **Appearance** > **Divi Theme Options** > **Custom CSS** (which is located at the bottom of the first tab in **Theme Options**). Something like:

```
.custom_fixed_toggles .et_pb_toggle {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```